# What is the difference between navigationBarTitle and navigationTitle modifiers in SwiftUI 2.0?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Learning all the new SwiftUI 2.0 changes but came across `.navigationTitle` which seems to work almost exactly like `.navigationBarTitle`. I looked at the WWDC 2020 videos and found one video where it was mentioned as being used to distinguish tab titles in MacOS? But not sure if it I should use it now instead of `.navigationBarTitle` in iOS? Also the Apple documentation is not clear about the differences between the two..

So my question is, what are the exact differences and how would you use them in iOS/MacOS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `navigationBarTitle` is just deprecated and renamed to `navigationTitle`:

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, renamed: "navigationTitle(_:)")
@available(macOS, unavailable)
@available(tvOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, renamed: "navigationTitle(_:)")
@available(watchOS, introduced: 6.0, deprecated: 100000.0, renamed: "navigationTitle(_:)")
public func navigationBarTitle(_ title: Text) -> some View
```

Comment: oh okay, so we shouldn't use `.navigationBarTitle` in Xcode anymore? Xcode 12 is still able to use it but I guess they will remove that before official release?

Comment: Not so fast, but at some day, yes.